# Subdomain can't be reached

Tags: subdomain, ping

I've asked a client to create a subdomain to his domain. He sent me back a small screenshot showing the following:

```
subdomain | 3600 | IN | NS | domain.1.to.point.to.com
subdomain | 3600 | IN | NS | domain.2.to.point.to.com
subdomain | 3600 | IN | NS | domain.3.to.point.to.com
subdomain | 3600 | IN | NS | domain.4.to.point.to.com
```

That was 3 days ago. Now I still can't access the subdomain either by ping or normal browsing.
Other odd thing is that I can't ping the client's domain like so:

```
ping domain.com
```

But I can ping:

```
ping www.domain.com
```

Is that normal?

Anyway would anyone know why the subdomain doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: Use dig to resolve the address, echos may not be allowed on domain.com. `dig domain.com`
Also, what does `dig -t ns subdomain.domain.com` come back with? Lastly, a sub-domain means that you will control names under *.subdomain.domain.com.  Is that your end goal?
From the looks of your config, you don't have any A records defined, and so `ping subdomain.domain.com` will not work

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick reply, here's a dump of `dig -t ns subdomain.domain.com:

http://pastebin.com/iTQkejMe

Also, no I don't want to control other names, I just need this address to point to my own server where I can host some files for them, like javascript and HTML

Comment: Then you don't need a subdomain, instead you need an A record for subdomain.domain.com (not NS). An A record is mapping a host name to ipaddress. In this case, wufoo.krb.nsw.edu.au IN A 1.2.3.4

Comment: And then it will point to my Route 53 settings?
Put your response as an answer and I'll validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you need an A record, not a subdomain (NS record) record. A subdomain allows you to control names under *.subdomain.domain.com. For example if you had this subdomain defined:

```
 wufoo.krb.nsw.edu.au.          IN      NS   mycontrolled.domain.com.
```

then mycontrolled.domain.com is the authority for any request under  wufoo.krb.nsw.edu.au.  A DNS client looking up `www.wufoo.krb.nsw.edu.au.` will ask  mycontrolled.domain.com for the A record.

Again, an A record for wufoo.krb.nsw.edu.au should allow you to connect to your webserver (assume that it is a webserver). 
I'm not to familiar with Amazon's Route53 product.  I cannot answer to that unless you tell us a little more about your setup.

Comment: Thou now the client says that to create a A record he need an IP address to the server. Do I need Route 53 then? Maybe he can just point to my server?

Comment: It doesn't appear you need Route 53, he can simply point to your server